# SQLiteBindOrColumnIndexOutOfRangeException when using selectionArgs

Tags: android, sqlite, sql-like

When I make a query in a such way

```
String where = "_id in(select phrase_id from words where word like '%FIRST%' intersect select phrase_id from words where word like '%SECOND%')";
Cursor cursor = database.query(PHRASES_TABLE, columns, where, null, null, null, null);
```

it works correctly. But when i try to use selectionArgs instead of hardcoded values

```
String where = "_id in(select phrase_id from words where word like '%?%' intersect select phrase_id from words where word like '%?%')";
String[] args = {"FIRST", "SECOND"};
Cursor cursor = database.query(PHRASES_TABLE, columns, where, args, null, null, null);
```

I catch 

`android.database.sqlite.SQLiteBindOrColumnIndexOutOfRangeException: bind or column index out of range: handle 0x10b71e0`

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`?` placeholder cannot be in a string literal but you can use SQL string concatenation `||` to combine `?` with `%` literal:

```
String where = "_id in(select phrase_id from words where word like '%' || ? || '%' intersect select phrase_id from words where word like '%' || ? || '%')";
```